# How can I apply orange3-made model to my Jupiter notebook program properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, orange

Firstly, I've saved the model from Orange3 as temp.pkcls
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCGV4.png)

I've load model as this code

```
with open("temp.pkcls", "rb") as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
```

Then I've tried

```
predicts = model.predict(X_test)
```

The result of predicts is as following

> (array([0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([[0.43952093, 0.33988087, 0.2205982 ],
>           [0.43989096, 0.33966234, 0.22044671]],[0.43952093, 0.33988087, 0.2205982 ],[0.43952093, 0.33988087, 0.2205982 ]))

I've no idea with the orange3-made model result but the right result from notebook-made model should be something like this (Classification problem)

> array(['Logician', 'Supporter', 'Adapter', 'Supporter'], dtype='

The question is how can I properly save model from orange3 and applying on my Jupyter notebook program

Comment: hey, did u find a way?